# Finding the sum of the digits of a factorial

Tags: ruby, algorithm

factorial_sum(5) should return 3. The error I'm getting is that "inject is an undefined method". I was also wondering if it's possible to combine the two functions. I wasn't sure as I am just starting out on recursion. Thanks!

```
def factorial_sum(x)
    factorial = factorial(x)
    factorial.to_s.split('').collect { |i| i.to_i }
    sum = factorial.inject { |sum, n| sum + n }
end

def factorial(x)
    if x < 0
        return "Negative numbers don't have a factorial"
    elsif x == 0
        1
    else
        factorial = x * factorial(x - 1)
    end
end

puts factorial_sum(5)
```

Comment: Do you mean "sum of digits"?

Comment: Yes sorry that is what I meant. It's edited!

Comment: Use `irb` and `.inspect` to debug your ruby.  Break your problem down into smaller bits if you're having trouble with your code.  Examine the ouptut of each line, and verify it does what you think it does.  Finally, I recommend not using the same variable name twice.  Remember, in ruby, functions are first class citizens of the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
factorial.to_s.split('').collect { |i| i.to_i }
```

This line is a no-op. You build a list and then throw it away. You probably meant `factorial = ...`

I have to say though that this would be pretty easy to find with a little effort and some print statements...

By the way, here's a slightly more concise way:

```
(1..x).reduce(:*).to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make it just one function and still use recursion?

Comment: @user Not sure what you're asking, that sounds like an arbitrary (non-)restriction. Every program can be expressed recursively, because typed lambda calculus is Turing complete.

Comment: Right now it's 2 methods. I'm trying to make it one method. However, I don't know how to deal with the recursion when I combine the two.

Comment: @user2469211 The separation into the "compute the factorial" and "sum the digits" part is sensible, so I would keep it separate functions as well, unless you can figure out a way to compute the digit sum without actually computing the factorial (which would be nice, but not really necessary I guess)

Comment: Sum the digits is dependent on the decimal system, while factorial is independent of it, so it makes more sense to have them separated.

Answer (score 2):

A direct way without temporarily converting it into strings, and without recursion.

```
s, q = 0, 120
while q > 0
  q, r = q.divmod(10)
  s += r
end
s # => 3
```

Comment: @NiklasB. You are right. That was my mistake. Thanks.